# Three-particle model (Hamiltonian)

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, potential-theory

The particles have mass $m=8$ and we assume that particles $i$ and $j$, having coordinates $x_i$ and $x_j$, interact via the potential
$$
U_{ij}(r_{ij})=16+q_iq_j\frac{16}{\cosh(r_{ij})},~r_{ij}=x_j-x_i.
$$

The Hamiltonian of the three-particle system is
$$
H=\frac{m}{2}\sum_{j=1}^3 v_j^2+U_{12}(r_{12})+U_{13}(r_{13})+U_{23}(r_{23})~~(*),
$$
where $v_j=dx_j/dt$.

Without loss of generality, we assume that the total momentum in the system is equal to zero, i.e. $m(v_1+v_2+v_3)=0$.

> > Introducing new variables
> >     $$
> > x_2-x_1\to\sqrt{3}\alpha+\beta,~~x_3-x_1\to 2\beta,~~t\to\sqrt{2m}t,
> > $$
> >     the Hamiltonian of $(*)$ can be presented in the form
> >     $$
> > H=\frac{1}{2}\left(\dot{\alpha}^2+\dot{\beta}^2\right)+U_{12}(\sqrt{3}\alpha+\beta)+U_{13}(2\beta)+U_{23}(\sqrt{3}\alpha-\beta)~~(2),
> > $$
> >     **which is the Hamiltonian of a unit-mass particle moving in the two-dimensional scattering potential.**

I have two-questions to the yellow box content:

(1) How do I get from the Hamiltonian $(*)$ to the new Hamiltonian $(2)$?

(2) Why is $(2)$ the Hamiltonian of a unit-mass particle moving in the two-dim. scattering potential? I do not understand how this is meant.

Comment: (1) You perform the change of variables that are given. (2) It simply means that the form of the Hamiltonian we get in the new variables $(\alpha,\beta)$ is the same as if they were the $(x,y)$ coordinates of some particle moving in some 2D scattering potential.

Comment: (1) My problem is I do not exactly know how to perfom the change of variables. (2) I do not understand why we now have **one** particle while before we have three. And why moving in a 2D-potential, isn't it three dim. since we have $U_{12}, U_{13}$ and $U_{23}$?

Comment: As for (2): we don't *have* one particle - we just transformed it into a Hamiltonian in some variables that has dynamics just like it was one particle moving in some 2D potential. It's no acctual particle here, it's just an analogy. Why is this useful? It might be easier to solve it this way. It might help you gain some intuition on how the system will evolve.

Comment: As for (1): Start by expressing $x_1,x_2,x_3$ in terms of $\alpha,\beta$ using the two equations and $v_1+v_2+v_3 = 0 \implies x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = C$ where we can take $C = 0$ by shifting the coordinate system. I find something like $x_1 = -\beta - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\alpha$ and $x_2 = \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\alpha$ and $x_3 = \beta - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\alpha$. Insert this into the Hamiltonian and try to simplify. Start with the term $\frac{m}{2}[\dot{x_1}^2 + \dot{x_2}^2 + \dot{x_3}^2]$